# get keys and vlaues from dictionary except "foreach"

Tags: c#, .net, linq

i have:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> matchesLists = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
if (matchesLists.ContainsKey("Errors"))
{
    var dict = GetInnerTextMatches(webDriver);
    dict.Keys.ToList().ForEach(k => matchesLists["Errors"].Add(k, dict[k]));
}
else
    matchesLists.Add("Errors", GetInnerTextMatches(webDriver));
```

`GetInnerTextMatches(webDriver)` returns `Dictionary<string,string>`

whether there is an easier way to add dictionary to matchesLists["Errors"]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're adding to an *existing* dictionary which has been returned by something else. I wouldn't do that - it ends up causing potentially confusing behaviour. I'd write that code as this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> errors;
if (!matchesLists.TryGetValue("Errors", out errors))
{
    errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    matchesLists["Errors"] = errors;
}
foreach (var entry in GetInnerTextMatches(webDriver))
{
    errors.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
}
```

That way you know that however `GetInnerTextMatches` is implemented, it doesn't matter - you're not going to interfere with it, and any internal changes to the dictionary returned by it won't interfere with you either.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 4 you can use [ConcurrentDictionary class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) and method `AddOrUpdate()`, if .NET 4 is a case for you see  [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378665.aspx)